# Read sharepoint page title from list

Tags: sharepoint, title, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint 2007 page which display news details dynamically from a list using query string , all the news is displayed in page `NewsDetails.aspx` like this `NewsDetails.aspx?ID=112`, what i want to do is making the page title read from the news list so that it displayed deferent for every page depending on the news title in the page to make the website more search engine friendly ,

i have noticed that the page title come from

```
 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_homelink_text%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/> 
- 
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>
```

is there a way to change this `<%$Resources:wss,multipages_homelink_text%>` to a list filed value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the master page and replace the content of the PlaceHolderPageTitle placeholder with your custom control. This custom control can check if the requested url contains NewsDetails.aspx if so you can set you custom text in all other cases you  can display the multipages_homelink_text

Comment: how could i create this custom control ? keeping in mind i can only use SharePoint designer

Comment: So it can be that you are screwed. :( However you can check Content Query Web Part according to this posthttp://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/14/what-s-new-with-the-content-query-web-part.aspx you could be able to read some data from teh query string (ID).  You could also create a custom page layout and assign it to the your pages and overwrite the PlaceHolderPageTitle only in this pagelayout. Never done this before so I'm just guessing.

Comment: thank you for your help  , there is always the java script abroach .. but this will not help with SEO as the engine bot will always read the hard-coded title (i think )